# I want only managers to acces a hidden view Lotus Notes 9

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

How can I let only managers to acces a certain view, what do i need to write in the PostOpen of the view(lotusscript),

TY very much guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK there is a "Security Tab" in the view design editor where you can specify who (person,roles) can use the view. No script necessary. The view will be hidden for persons that is not allow to access the view.

Comment: @user2764473: create a role [Admin], give all Administrators this role and then you can choose this role in "Security Tab"

Answer (score 2):

As you are not describing in your question, why you want to hide the view, here are a view general comments:

1. Hiding a view from a group of people does not limit access to certain documents to this group of people. Unless the documents are otherwise protected, users can create private views and folders that display the documents shown in the restricted view. If you do not want to grant them access to the documents, please use reader fields.
2. "Managers" in the ACL have the right to change the database ACL, ... In regards to read access to documents, there is no difference to "Reader"s, as long as you are not using Reader fields in documents.
3. If you meant "Managers" as a role, please follow Peter's and Knuth's advice but keep in mind once more that limiting access to a view does not limit access to the documents via another view.

For more details on access rights, ... please take a look at [Access levels in the ACL](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/7.0/help7_designer.nsf/0/1f4e7e9e5c9898a78525704a003f6861), [Roles in the ACL](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/7.0/help7_designer.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/d202782d5a62a5728525704a003f68c4?OpenDocument), [Creating read access lists to limit view and folder access](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/rnext/help6_designer.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/06749ddca026158185256c54004b932e?OpenDocument) and [The Domino security model](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.help.domino.admin.doc/DOC/H_OVERVIEW_OF_DOMINO_AND_NOTES_SECURITY_3811_OVERVIEW_MIDTOPIC_419071600029232126.html).

Comment: No i am not refering to the role, i am refering to the acces. and i want only people that have manager acces to see and open the view. I dont have a "manager" role or a "manager" group